# Is Interlocked.CompareExchange's parameters part of the atomic operation?

Tags: c#, atomic

Will the following statement (adressing the same variable as first and third parameter) allways cause variable b to get the value of variable c upon completion or is it possible for another thread to change one or more of the parameters while they are fetched causing the first and third parameter to contain different values during the compare operation ?

```
a = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref b, c, b)
```

Comment: Seems like it would take about two minutes to write a test that tries it. Of course that would only answer the question definitively if the answer was that yes it can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an interesting question; I suspect the answer is "it isn't guaranteed", simply because the field's value can trivially be changed after the `ldfld` (the final parameter) but before it has been evaluated via the address (obtained previously via `ldflda`), but this is largely academic, as with threading code like this, the important thing is to do something demonstrably right.

Clearly "it isn't guaranteed" wouldn't allow us to determine much, so would be useless. If we *wanted* an answer of "it is guaranteed", then the question becomes moot, as it could be easier and more obvious to simply use `Interlocked.Exchange`.

Comment: Clarification: `b` could also be a `ref` argument, in which case `ldarg`/`ldarga` - but the rest stands, I suspect

Comment: Additional clarification: the value of `b` could have *already changed*, i.e. before `ldfld` / `ldarg` - and yet we could have re-loaded an old value from our local cache (assuming it isn't marked `volatile`, which would create a compiler-warning for the `ref`)